# Error Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: S. Path '', line 0, position 0.'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, api, asp.net-web-api

Estou com esse problema, acredito que seja algo em Json, mas já tentei de tudo e não estou conseguindo retornar os objetos.

My code:

```
        public List<Product> List()
        {
            var retorno = new List<Product>();
            try
            {
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("GET"), "https://teste.teste1.com.br/app/Api/V1/Products/list"))
                    {
                        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-user-email", "victor@teste.com.br");
                        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-api-key", "eyJ0edsasa3121dasdas312dsa");
                        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-store-key", "1");
                        request.Content = new StringContent("Content-Type", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("accept", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
                        var response = client.SendAsync(request);
                        //var response = client.GetStringAsync(uprApi + "app/Api/V1/Products/list");
                        response.Wait();
                        retorno = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product[]>(response.Result.ToString()).ToList();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
            return retorno;
        }
```

**Erro:**

Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: S. Path '', line 0, position 0.'

**EDIT:**

My json:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "offset": 0,
    "result": {
        "error": false,
        "registers_count": 5,
        "pages_count": 1,
        "page": 1,
        "data": [
            {
                "product": {
                    "sku": "01",
                    "name": "Produto teste 01",
                    "description": "Produto de teste 01.",
                    "status": "enabled",
                    "qty": 30,
                    "price": 149.9,
                    "list_price": 199.9,
                    "weight_gross": 0.1,
                    "weight_liquid": 0.1,
                    "height": 1,
                    "width": 1,
                    "length": 1,
                    "items_per_package": "1",
                    "brand": "Colcci",
                    "ean": null,
                    "ncm": null,
                    "categories": [
                        {
                            "code": "339",
                            "name": "ESPORTES/Academia e Fitness/Roupas"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "product": {
                    "sku": "3",
                    "name": "Produto DESATIVADO",
                    "description": "xyz",
                    "status": "disabled",
                    "qty": 0,
                    "price": 5.8,
                    "list_price": null,
                    "weight_gross": 0.1,
                    "weight_liquid": 0.1,
                    "height": 1,
                    "width": 1,
                    "length": 1,
                    "items_per_package": "1",
                    "brand": "Colcci",
                    "ean": null,
                    "ncm": null,
                    "categories": [
                        {
                            "code": null,
                            "name": null
                        }
                    ],
                    "variation_attributes": [
                        "UN"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "product": {
                    "sku": "2",
                    "name": "Produto X",
                    "description": "xyz",
                    "status": "enabled",
                    "qty": 0,
                    "price": 5.8,
                    "list_price": null,
                    "weight_gross": 0.1,
                    "weight_liquid": 0.1,
                    "height": 1,
                    "width": 1,
                    "length": 1,
                    "items_per_package": "1",
                    "brand": "Colcci",
                    "ean": null,
                    "ncm": null,
                    "categories": [
                        {
                            "code": null,
                            "name": null
                        }
                    ],
                    "variation_attributes": [
                        "UN"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "product": {
                    "sku": "1",
                    "name": "Produto",
                    "description": "Descrição do Produto Criado",
                    "status": "disabled",
                    "qty": 176,
                    "price": 5.9,
                    "list_price": 5.8,
                    "weight_gross": 0.1,
                    "weight_liquid": 0.1,
                    "height": 1,
                    "width": 1,
                    "length": 1,
                    "items_per_package": "1",
                    "brand": "Colcci",
                    "ean": "7896044963486",
                    "ncm": null,
                    "categories": [
                        {
                            "code": "3",
                            "name": "FEMININO/Roupas/Blusas e Camisas"
                        }
                    ],
                    "variations": [
                        {
                            "sku": "P_B",
                            "qty": 12,
                            "EAN": null,
                            "price": 5.8,
                            "list_price": 5.8,
                            "images": [],
                            "variant": [
                                {
                                    "size": "p"
                                },
                                {
                                    "color": "Branco"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "sku": "M_P",
                            "qty": 14,
                            "EAN": null,
                            "price": 5.8,
                            "list_price": 5.8,
                            "images": [],
                            "variant": [
                                {
                                    "size": "m"
                                },
                                {
                                    "color": "Preto"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "sku": "ABC1",
                            "qty": 150,
                            "EAN": null,
                            "price": 5.9,
                            "list_price": 5.8,
                            "images": [],
                            "variant": [
                                {
                                    "size": "p"
                                },
                                {
                                    "color": "Azul"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "product": {
                    "sku": "GG004",
                    "name": "Gabinete Gamer",
                    "description": "Gabinete Gamer com RGB",
                    "status": "enabled",
                    "qty": 6,
                    "price": 399.9,
                    "list_price": 399.9,
                    "weight_gross": 0.3,
                    "weight_liquid": 0.25,
                    "height": 9,
                    "width": 3,
                    "length": 5,
                    "items_per_package": "1",
                    "brand": "Colcci",
                    "ean": null,
                    "ncm": null,
                    "categories": [
                        {
                            "code": "276",
                            "name": "CELULARES & ELETRÔNICOS/Informática/Games"
                        }
                    ],
                    "images": [
                        "https://manairadigitalteste.conectala.com.br/app/assets/images/product_image/4B3451F8-C862-7884-D169-5F256FA31F91/16581443192118.jpg"
                    ],
                    "published_marketplace": {
                        "ManairaDigital": "5_ManairaDigital"
                    },
                    "marketplace_offer_links": [
                        {
                            "name": "ManairaDigital",
                            "href": "https://manairadigital.com.br/gabinete-gamer-29/p"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

O problema está no tipo passado pra desserializar. Quando chama `DeserializeObject()`, está usando `Product[]`, mas se olhar a estrutura do Json, não parece ser o tipo correto.

Perceba que, até chegar na lista de produtos, precisa passar por `result.data` primeiro, e ainda assim é uma lista de objetos contendo, cada um, uma propriedade `product`.

Confere se tua classe pra desserializar tá certa (seria interessante postar o código da classe `Product` também) e ajeita ela pra estar de acordo com a estrutura do JSON (pelo menos, dos campos que tu pretende acessar)

---

Edit:

Dá uma olhada [nesse fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/B0N72r). Fiz um exemplo de como seria uma classe pra desserializar esse JSON.